# Random walk with stop condition

Tags: r, random-walk

I have the following generator code for a random walk:

```
i = 1
t = 100
p = 0.5

max_walk = 1000

samples = rbinom(max_walk, 1, p)
samples[samples==0] = -1
walk = c(i, cumsum(samples))
```

In my case i is the value of the first step, and t would be the maximum value and zero the minimum. So my walk would have to stop when the value is less than or equal to zero or greater than or equal to t.

Is there any way to do this? Or maybe the cumsum doesn't add up when the respective result is less than or equal to zero or greater than or equal to t?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your code, your random walk starts at 1 and each step moves 0 or +1 with equal probability. In this way, it will never hit 0 as this is a constant upward drift. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Your code shows that each step is -1 or 1 so the minimum value is not 0. The actual possible range (although very unlikely) is -999 to 1001 (since you start with 1).

Comment: I edited the post. I ended up expressing myself in the wrong way. Excuse me. I want it to stop "walking" when it finds a value less than or equal to zero or greater than or equal to t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a loop using `while()`, but it is simpler just to run your code as written and then identify the stop point:

```
stop <- which(walk < 1 | walk > max_walk)
stop[1]                # First stop
# [1] 13
walk[stop[1]]          # Value at first stop
# [1] 0
plot(walk, type="l")   # Plot entire walk
points(stop[1], walk[stop[1]], col="red")
```

[image: Random Walk]